# IDLE fechando sozinha ao pressionar aspa

Tags: python, osx

Até hoje eu estava usando o próprio terminal para programar em Python, porém hoje resolvi baixar o IDLE.
Quando tento colocar a aspa simples ( ' ) ele simplesmente fecha.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você alterou alguma configuração recentemente? Já olhou se a aspa simples está definida como atalho? Vá em `Options` - `Configure IDLE` - aba `Keys`.

Comment: Consegui ajeitar. Precisava instalar a versão 8.5.18 do Tlc/TK

Comment: Que ótimo. Se possível poste como resposta (e aceite ela) a resolução do problema. =)

Comment: Postei. Devo esperar dois dias para aceitar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Apenas em OS X**

Deve-se instalar a versão 8.5.18 do Tlc/Tk, encontrada no site: http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads

Mais informações indicadas na documentação do próprio site da Python, encontrada no link: https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/

Comment: Caro Gabriel, também existe a possibilidade de você usar o IPython, uma IDE interativa e super legal de ser utilizada, já que ela gera gráficos e etc.

Answer (score 2):

IDLE usa Tkinter da biblioteca padrão do Python para fornecer funcionalidades GUI. Tkinter é uma interface para a interface gráfica da multi-platformTk, parte de Tcl / Tk. Infelizmente,  no OS X atualmente não suporta todas as características padrão de processamento de texto no Mac OS X.

Simplesmente mude o teclado para EUA no lugar de EUA internacional